# flot chart plothover event fires but item is always null in bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I'm using flot chart to display issue occurrence data over time on shoppimon.com.
when using line chart my flothover function works perfectly, but as soon as I switch to a bar chart the tooltip stops showing.
When debugging, I break inside the flothover callback, which means that the event is firing, but the "item" parameter is always null.

Any advise is much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
renderChart : function(containerId) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var data = chartServer.getData(containerId);
        var container = $('#' + containerId);
        if (window.localStorage && window.localStorage['cbMode'] == 'true') {
            data.options.colors = chartClient.cbColors;
        } else {
            data.options.colors = chartClient.chartColors;
        }
        container.before('<div id="' + containerId + '-controls" class="chart-controls group"> \
            <div class="chart-legend" /> ');

        //Plot the chart
        var chart = $.plot(container, data.dataSet, data.options);

        container.bind('plothover', chartClient.hoverFunction);
        container.bind('plotclick', chartClient.clickFunction);

        container.bind('plothover', function(event, pos, item) {
            if (item) {
                $(event.target).css({cursor:"pointer"});
            } else {
                $(event.target).css({cursor:"auto"});
            }
        });
    }, 100);
},

hoverFunction : function(event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        if (chartClient.previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
            chartClient.previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
            $("#chart-tooltip").remove();
            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(0);

            var date = new Date(parseInt(x, 10));
            date.add({minutes: Date.today().getTimezoneOffset()}); // compensate for local TZ
            var contents = date.toString("MMM d ") + date.toString("t") + "<br />" + y + " times";

            $('<div id="chart-tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                top: item.pageY + 5,
                left: item.pageX + 5
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        }
    } else {
        $("#chart-tooltip").remove();
        chartClient.previousPoint = null;
    }
},
```

This is my options object:

```
Object {xaxis: Object, grid: Object, legend: Object, series: Object, colors: Array[5]}
colors: Array[5]0: "#0073B5"1: "#6A4A3C"2: "#CC333F"3: "#EB6841"4: "#EDC951"
length: 5

grid: Object
borderColor: "#EDEDED"
borderWidth: 1
clickable: true
hoverable: true

legend: Object
container: "#occurrence-chart-39631-controls .chart-legend"
noColumns: 1

series: Object

bars: Object
fill: true
show: true

xaxis: Object
mode: "time"
```

Comment: Are you switching from line chart to bar chart dynamically?

Comment: No, I test once with line chart - works. Changing the options to bar abd test again - item is null.

Comment: The only thing that jumps out at me is your `<div id="chart-tooltip">` needs a `position: 'absolute'`.  Other than that you'll need to create a reproducable example.  There's just too much missing code and data above to even guess.  I attempted to reproduce here (http://plnkr.co/edit/jKHv1gQ1n7sLB6wPaz1c?p=preview) but there's just not enough information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

So, in order to get the item object inside the flotHover event handler you have to include the data points in your chart, using the following "points" option:

```
    $options['grid']['clickable'] = true;
    $options['grid']['hoverable'] = true;
    $options['series'] = array(
        'bars' => array('show' => true),
        'points' => array('show' => true, 'radius' => 0, 'symbol' => 'square')
    );
```

If you want to avoid showing those points, you can use a radius of 0 like I did. The hover function still works, and the item object exist in the callback, but no visible change to the chart bars.

Comment: Also if you have provided a `transform: ` function for your data set, you need to provide an `inverseTransform: ` function, too.